# Change Interval Of CADisplayLink

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have replaced an `NSTimer` with a `CADisplayLink`. I have it working properly but it is running too slowly. How could I go about speeding this up? This is the code that I'm using:

In the interface I declare an instance variable:

```
CADisplayLink *displayLink;
```

In viewDidLoad I create the object:

```
displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(onTimer)];
[displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

The method that gets called is `onTimer`. So my question is: how do I speed up how often this is being called?

Comment: Why do you need to update more often than once per screen refresh?

Comment: As David's question suggests: running a timer faster than the screen refresh is almost always an indication of a mistake in the design. It's usually either a mistake in your model layer (often using the view layer to hold state), or an accidental attempt to recreate Core Animation. Remember: neither `NSTimer` nor `CADisplayTimer` are meant to be "real time" timers.

Answer (score 4):

`CADisplayLink` is a timer that is *bound* to refresh rate of the display. It's a specific tool for a specific task: don't draw when unnecessary.

If you don't need this, simply use NSTimer with whatever interval you need.

If you need to call your method at some specific intervals that depend on refresh rate (e.g. you need to do something twice between re-draws), you have to slightly modify your scheduler.
There are 2 properties of your concern: [`-[CADisplayLink timestamp]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CADisplayLink/timestamp) and [`-[CADisplayLink duration]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CADisplayLink/duration). You can calculate time of next call based on these properties.

Comment: How do I assign those properties to my 'CADisplayLink'? I have notices 'displayLink.timestamp'. Is this it and if so how do I use it?

Comment: That's it, you do not need to *modify* `CADisplayLink`. Use your own timer and calculate fire date by using these properties of `CADisplayLink`.

Comment: Be aware that if your render loop is longer than the frame interval, the `CADisplayLink timestamp` and `duration` properties will not return real-time values. For example, if you have set a `frameInterval` of 1, `duration` will always report 16.7 ms, and the time between two successive `timestamp` values will always be a multiple of 16.7 ms. But if your render loop takes 20 ms, `CADisplayLink` will run again immediately. It does not wait for the next 60 Hz cycle, and the real time between two successive loops will be 20 ms (which you can verify by taking real-time timestamps).

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else looking here. It is somewhat possible to achieve this effect. By changing the `preferredFramesPerSecond` property. (`frameInterval` for pre iOS 10). 
Although, Kentzo is right in saying this should only be used where specifically required. Else, use NSTimer.